# How can I combine Postgresgl's ArrayField ANY option with LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to filter a queryset on the first characters of an element in an ArrayField in postgresql.

```
Data
--------------------
|  id  | registration_date  |  sbi_codes           |
|  1   |    2007-11-13      |  {9002, 1002, 85621} |
|  2   |    2010-10-11      |  {1002, 9022, 9033   |
|  3   |    2019-02-02      |  {9001, 8921}  |
|  4   |    2012-02-02      |  {120}               |
```

I've tried the following (which obviously don't work), but I think clearly indicates what I'm trying to achieve.

```
select count(*)
from administrations_administration
where '90' = left(any(sbi_codes),2)
```

or

```
select count(*)
from administrations_administration
where '90%' like any(sbi_codes
```

So the sbi_codes can be for example 9002 or 9045, And I'm trying to filter all the records that contain an element that starts with 90.

expected result

```
____
| count | sbi_codes  |
|  3    | 90          |
```

Thanks!

Comment: PLease review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a successful answer. You are lacking sample date, as text - **No Imges**, the desired results of that data and the DDL for your table.

Answer (score 0):

The thing on the left hand side of LIKE is the string, in which % is just a %.  The thing on the right hand side is the pattern, in which % is a wildcard.  Using ANY does't change these semantics, the pattern still goes the right.

To solve this, you [could create your own operator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228235/match-string-pattern-to-any-array-element/228262#228262) which is like LIKE, but has its arguments reversed.